# Return code from sudo block command

Tags: linux, bash, ksh

I have this example script (in KSH but I think it doesn't matter) which I run under userAAA:

```
#!/bin/sh
aa=1
sudo su - userBBB <<SUDO
  bb=1
  let cc=\$bb+$aa
  exit \$cc
SUDO

echo $?
```

Does exist some way how to get to returned code of sudo (without using saving into file)?

Comment: That script should be echoing the exit code from `sudo`. Is that not happening? That said the script should probably also *exit* with the exit code of `sudo` (or *only* exit with the exit code from `sudo`).

Comment: When you want to see `$cc`, use `echo "$cc"`. You can capture the value with `su_cc=$(sudo...)`.

Comment: So I tried it with echo and it really works. I think there is not another way because in SUDO I'm opening new terminal which cannot return its return code. Thx Walter. ;]